# django migration don't work on server

Tags: python, django, migration, models

I had a app where there were models and that site I have deployed. Now I have added 2 models in the app. Unfortunately my migration was deleted in local and after adding the models I again generated the migration with 2 new models.

It gives me 0001_initial.py where I can see my new models too. Now I updated my this file in server. But when I did python manage.py migrate it says "Some of your model has been changed but not reflected so do manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate"

I tried "python manage.py migrate" but it says same thing. I am unable to get these models. I have even tried "python manage.py syncdb" but same error.

I have registered these models in admin so in admin I am seeing these models but when I click it my servers get hang. I think because my models are not synchronised or my new tables are not created.

In my migration i can see the new models too but when I do "manage.py migrate" i get errors that I should migrate first and re-migrate.

Is there anyway so that I can compel my app to use that migration forcefully where I have my new models too.

I am trying this from hours but no solution. Need help

Comment: I've had to manually migrate (i.e. update the database manually) most of my models when uploading to my production server unless it's a brand new model that doesn't already exist.  I've had terrible times trying to align my migration files, so I've disregarded them completely.

Comment: Mine is brand new models. I am changing any old models. But also its not migrating. Can you guide me how to do it manually?